# Is there a way to insert XFA form values on a reader enabled LiveCycle PDF with itext 7 using append mode?

Tags: itext, itext7

I need to input XFA form field values into a LiveCycle reader-enabled PDF using iText 7. I can do this successfully but if I don't open the PDF in append mode then it appears the Adobe signature gets broken and the form values cannot be further edited by a user and saved again. If I open the PDF with iText 7 in append mode and change the XFA form field values, the signature from being reader-enabled does not get broken but the changed values aren't showing up on the form. It seems like a bug with iText 7 and changing XFA form field values with append mode possibly. Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: Hello. Please show us your code. This will help to figure out whether the problem is in the approach you chose or is it a bug in iText

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in filling XFA Forms in append mode in `iText7`. This has been fixed in `7.0.2` (and `7.0.2-SNAPSHOT`).

The fill a form in append mode, you need the following piece of code:

```
PdfDocument pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST), 
                                         new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfdoc, true);
XfaForm xfa = form.getXfaForm();
xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(XML));
xfa.write(pdfdoc);

pdfdoc.close();
```